# the lights of the traffic light do not display Such As the amber red and green

Tags: html

What is supposed to happen is
 that when the button is clicked the traffic will rotate in order of the colors. so it would start with red then amber and lastly green and then repeat itself after when you press the button. Thank you for the help

```
<DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Marcus's Traffic Lights </title>
<script>

function light() {  
    setTimeout(Picture1, 4000)
    setTimeout(Picture2, 2000)
    setTimeout(Picture3, 6000) 

}

fuction Picture1() 
    document.getElementById("red").style.visabillity='visible';
document.getElementById("green").style.visabillity='visible';
}

fuction Picture2() 
    document.getElementById("red").style.visabillity='visible';
document.getElementById("amber").style.visabillity='visible';

}

</script>

</head>
<body>

<div id="rectangle"style="
    width:125px;
    height:350px;   
    background:black;
    position: absolute;
    left 0px;-1;">
</div>
THIS DOES NOT DISPLAY
<div id="red" style="visiabllity:hidden; width: 100px;
 height: 100px;                      
 background: red;
 -moz-border-radius: 50px
 -webkit-border-radius: 50px;z-index: 10;
 border-radius: 50px;"></div>
THIS DOES NOT DISPLAY

<div id="orange" style="visiabllity:hidden; width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 background: orange;
 -moz-border-radius: 50px
 -webkit-border-radius: 50px;z-index: 10;
 border-radius: 50px;"></div>
THIS DOES NOT DISPLAY

<div id="green" style="visiabllity:hidden; width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 background: green;
 -moz-border-radius: 50px
 -webkit-border-radius: 50px;z-index: 10;
 border-radius: 50px;"></div>


<button onclick="light()"Start</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<body>
    <img id="trafficlights" src="Redlight.jpeg" style="width:128px;height:128px;">
    <button type="button" onclick="starttrafficlights()">Change Traffic Lights</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="stoptrafficlights()">Stop Traffic Lights</button>
<script>
    var position = 1, id;
    var list = ["Redlight.jpeg","RedAmberlight.jpeg","Greenlight.jpeg", "Amberlight"];  
    function changetrafficlights(){ 
            stop = true;
            var image = document.getElementById('trafficlights');
            image.src=list[position % list.length];
            position++;
    }
    function starttrafficlights(){
        id = setInterval(changetrafficlights, 1000);
    }
    function stoptrafficlights(){
        clearInterval(id);
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

if this solves your problem...